# Term for "substantivized adjectives" in French grammar

Tags: adjectifs

what is the term for substantivised adjectives in French grammar. I googled "substantivised adjectives in french" but very few pages are in this title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

J'ai trouvé deux variantes.

Soit:

**L’adjectif employé comme nom** http://research.jyu.fi/grfle/038.html

Soit:

**L'adjectif substantivé** http://perso.numericable.fr/eric.alglave/Grammaire/adjsubs.htm

Il existe aussi :

**Substantivation**

(voir le commentaire)

Comment: Merci beaucoup. voir aussi https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substantivation